# how to create a new page and upload a text file into the confluence space

Tags: confluence

i have a script that gets a text file as an output, i want this text file to be uploaded in the confluence space but i am not sure how to do it.
this is a sample script that i found off the internet but this is not working for me

```
    import urllib2
import base64
conf_serverurl = "https://confluence.mycompany.com/"
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"
stringToEncode = username + ":" + password
encodedString = base64.b64encode(stringToEncode)
url = conf_serverurl + "/rest/api/content?os_username=" + username + "&amp;os_password=" + password
data = '{"type":"page","ancestors":[{"type":"page","id":18166401}],"title":"new page","space":{"key":"ds"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"&lt;p&gt;This is a new page&lt;/p&gt;","representation":"storage"}}}'
headers = { 'Authentication': 'Basic ' + encodedString, 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check' }
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers=headers)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = response.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    data = error.read()
print data
```

but this code is throwing me the error

```
{"message":"null for uri: https://confluence.mycompany.com//rest/api/content?os_username=ppanda&amp;os_password=mypassword","status-code":404}
```

what can be wrong here??
credentials??/ code??

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind that you do have double `"/"` in your URL. Because in `conf_serverurl` you do have `"https://confluence.mycompany.com/"` and in your URL you will add `/rest/api/..`. So, I would say remove one of the `/` from your code and check.

Also, please take a look at [Atlassian Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples) for finding proper REST endpoint of creating page and uploading attachments.

Comment: i tried removing the extra '/'  but still does not work

Comment: i found this from the documentation curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":
"storage"}}}' http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/  but not sure what to replace http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ link with..is it http://mycompany.domain.com/confluence/rest/api/content/

Comment: Instead of that you need to put your Confluence Server Base URL

Comment: i am not sure what can be the local domain...https://confluence.mycompany.com/dashboard.action this is the dashboard link